# I couldnt set location of components in Java for usinf JFrame and contentPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, location, layout-manager

I want to create a simple profile information page with JFrame and contentPane. I added all the components correctly. But I cant set their location. How can i set it? I used setBoundary() method bur it doesnt work.

My Anket.java class is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

 

public class Anket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        frame.setTitle("Profile Information");
        
        
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

 

       
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Age(10-20)");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(412, 50, 50, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("Age(21-30)");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(412, 20, 50, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1);
            
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_2 = new JRadioButton("Age(31-40)");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(412, 30, 50, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_2);
                
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_3 = new JRadioButton("Age(41-50)");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(412, 40, 50, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_3);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("PLEASE ENTER YOUR INFORMATION");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(149, 0, 182, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Enter Your Name");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(127, 25, 86, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Enter Your Lastname");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(272, 25, 100, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("Enter Your Height");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(127, 103, 86, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_3);
        
        
        
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(216, 100, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JTextField textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(127, 48, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        
        JTextField textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);
        textField_2.setBounds(412, 48, 86, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        

 

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/PC/eclipse-workspace/Project/src/Berguzar.jpg"));
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(10, 21, 100, 85);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_4);
        
        
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

 

}
```

The program doesnt have any error. How can i fix this problem?

My output screen is:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFNZj.png)

Comment: You should use the layout manager to control your bounds rather than setBounds().

Comment: The frame is using a layout manager. The job of the layout manager is to set the size/location of each component based on the rules of the layout manager. So therefore the setBounds(...) statement is ignored. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. You can also nest panels using different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: Also, when you create a JTextField you use something like: `new JTextField(10)`. This will allow the text field to determine its preferred size so that it can display 10 "W" letters in the text field before scrolling is necessary. This will allow the layout managers to work more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

with

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null); // The null is important
contentPane.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
frame.setContentPane(contentPane); // each time you change the content pane you need to revalidate the jframe (frame.setVisible(true) also revalidate the jframe so in this case it is not needed to revalidate the jframe)
```